# How to manage multiple dependent droplist on edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have 4 model which value is dependent on each next model.
Let take 4 model :
(1) Equipment Type
(2) Equipment Brand
(3) Equipment Model
(4) Equipment

Here (2) depend on (1)'s value, (3) depend on (2)'s value, (4) depend on (3)'s value.

When I select value from droplist (1) then it will update (2)'s droplist value using make ajax call, when select value from droplist (2) then it will update (3)'s value using ajax call accordingly and so on.

This chain may be muliple.

[image]

For new form it will fine. No issue.

But when we going for update then How can we manage this all stuff in better way.

**I tried**

On page load set I have 4 model which value is dependent on each next model.
Let take 4 model :
(1) Equipment Type
(2) Equipment Brand
(3) Equipment Model
(4) Equipment

Here (2) depend on (1)'s value, (3) depend on (2)'s value, (4) depend on (3)'s value.

When I select value from droplist (1) then it will update (2)'s droplist value using make ajax call, when select value from droplist (2) then it will update (3)'s value using ajax call accordingly and so on.

This chain may be muliple.

[image]

For new form it will fine. No issue.

But when we going for update then How can we manage this all stuff in better way.

**I tried**

On page load

1) set Equipment Type value from DB.

```
// On page load
$(".equipment_type_cmb_box").each(function(){
  $(this).trigger('change');
})

$(function(){

  $(document).on('change', ".equipment_type_cmb_box", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get_equipment_brand_collection',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {equipment_type_id: $(this).val()},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
     // set equipment brand values in equipment brand droplist
     $(".equipment_brand_cmb_box").html('').select2({
         data: data.equipment_brands.map(function(obj){
           return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name} 
         })
     })
// change the value in droplist and fire change event to get next associated droplist data
  $(".equipment_brand_cmb_box").val(db_saved_value).trigger('change')
    })
    .fail(function(errorObject) {
        console.log("Error : ", errorObject.statusText);
     })
  })

  $(document).on('change', ".equipment_brand_cmb_box", function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/get_equipment_model_collection',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {equipment_brand_id: $(this).val()},
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        // set equipment model values in equipment model droplist
        $(".equipment_model_cmb_box").html('').select2({
          data: data.equipment_models.map(function(obj){
                  return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name} 
                })
        })
       // change the value in droplist and fire change event to get next associated droplist data
  $(".equipment_model_cmb_box").val(db_saved_value).trigger('change')
      })
      .fail(function(errorObject) {
        console.log("Error : ", errorObject.statusText);
      })
    })

    $(document).on('change', ".equipment_model_cmb_box", function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/get_equipment_collection',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {equipment_model_id: $(this).val()},
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        // set equipment values in equipment droplist
        $(".equipment_cmb_box").html('').select2({
          data: data.equipment.map(function(obj){
                  return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name} 
                })
        })
// change the value in droplist and fire change event to get next associated droplist data
       $(".equipment_cmb_box").val(db_saved_value).trigger('change')
      })
      .fail(function(errorObject) {
        console.log("Error : ", errorObject.statusText);
      })
    })
})
```

One cahin fire 3 ajax call to get equipment brand, equipment model, equipment data. So if I have 5 chain then it will fire 15 ajax call and that is not a better way to do so.

Can any one have better suggestion for that ?
It will be great if any one have proper solution for this situations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that will help you, but you might try caching the function that provides the options. That will reduce the api calls.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qq5zhwj/)

```
function getOptions(endpoint, data) {
  var hash = endpoint + JSON.stringify(data);
  if (typeof getOptions.cache[hash] !== "undefined") {
    console.log('Got data from cache');
    return Promise.resolve(getOptions.cache[hash]);
  }

  return $.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
  }).then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Got data from api');
    getOptions.cache[hash] = resp;
    return resp;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank's for you reply but it is not helpfull :( . Data may different in every chain of process. so we can not take result from cache. But yes it will helpfull  if same data needs multiple time. I will surly implemet this fundamental in other situation Thanks :) .